# Looping through nested objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm new to Javascript and working on building a quiz app. All of the quiz questions and answers are stored in an array in an object named 'quiz'. I'm trying to use a loop to get the app to cycle through the questions on click of a button. However, the loop I'm using seems to be freezing my page. Any pointers for where I'm going wrong?

```
//sample object
    quiz = {
        "questions": [
            {
                "question":"Question 1",
                "a":"Answer a1",
                "b":"Answer b1",
                "c":"Answer c1",
                "d":"Answer d1",
            },
            {
                "question":"Question 2",
                "a":"Answer a2",
                "b":"Answer b2",
                "c":"Answer c2",
                "d":"Answer d2",
            }
        ]
    }

//load next question on click   
        $("#next").click(function(){
            for (i=1; i<quiz.questions.length; i.next) {
               $("#question").text(quiz.questions[i].question);
            };
        });
```

Comment: `i.next` ====> `i++`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> for (i=1; i<quiz.questions.length; i.next) {
> ```

`i.next` doesn't modify the value of `i`. Since `i` is never modified, the second condition is never not met, so the loop is infinite.

Use `i++` instead.

---

> ```
> $("#question").text(quiz.questions[i].question);
> ```

Each time you go around the loop, you *replace* the text with the next question. You'll always end up with the last question.

You shouldn't use a `for` loop if you want to increment each time the button is pressed.

- Declare `i` outside the function.
- Remove the `for` loop entirely
- Put `i++` at the end of the function
- Test for when `i >= quiz.questions.length` and do … whatever you want to do when you run out of questions.

---

> ```
> i=1
> ```

On the subject of declaring `i`. JavaScript arrays start at `0`. You probably want to initialize it as `0` and not `1`.

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ — No. The loop goes until the condition is not met. Since that never happens, the loop is infinite.